# TypeScript object type: narrow key/value pairs to those where the value is of type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a TypeScript type that looks like this:

```
type Utilities = {
  getFeatureFlag: (name: string) => string;
  apiRequest: (endpoint: string) => Promise<object>;
  getConfig: (name: string) => Promise<object>;
}
```

And from this type, I want generate a subtype where the only key/value pairs to keep are those where the values are functions that return promises. So the resulting type would be the following (same, but with `getFeatureFlag` omitted):

```
type PromiseUtilities = {
  apiRequest: (endpoint: string) => Promise<object>;
  getConfig: (name: string) => Promise<object>;
}
```

Is it possible to do this with some set of TypeScript utilities or keywords?

Comment: From the answer to the linked question, you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL4Xbm).

Comment: perfect, thanks @jcalz!